# muti-threading best practices in mongoDB not-sharded collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a relatively big database 1TB with 3x layer nested arrays , but not sharded , I have found that running 100 paralel threads  is faster then processing with forEach() all the database to extract some fields from last layer (10h instead of 80h) .
So my question is:
Can I split the data to chunks based on date extracted from default document _id or what are the best practices to process all the data in the collection  in multiple paralel threads instead of 1 , is there any easy option to split in equal parts the data to all threads at once ?

( Doing skip() / limit() seems to be time consuming and not effective )

this is singe document example:

```
db.m.findOne()
{
"_id":ObjectId("56c5e1ca4537ddec8950ed20"),
"f":"xyz",
"apps":[

{
"aID":"mnk",
"aDate":"20210101",
"apId":"test1",
"proc":[
         {
          "procID":1,
      "procDate":"202101",        
      "s":{   
           "c":{     "t":[ {"sid":1 } ,{"sid":2} , {"sid":4}  ]},
           "d":{    "t":[ {"sid":7} , {"sid":46}  ]} ,
           "a":{    "t":[ {"sid":12 } ,{"sid":22} , {"sid":54}  ]} ,
          }
     },
     {
      "procID":2,
      "procDate":"202102",        
      "s":{   
           "c":{     "t":[ {"sid":200 }  ]},
           "d":{    "t":[ {"sid":700} , {"sid":200}  ]} ,
           "a":{    "t":[ {"sid":1 } ,{"sid":220}  ]} ,
          }
     }
     
    ]

}

]

}
```

And this is my attempt to split the query based on "apps.proc.procDate" field and make it  multithreading :

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind"  : "$apps"}, 
    {"$unwind"  : "$apps.proc"},
    {"$match"   : {"apps.proc.procDate" : date}},
    {"$limit"   : LIMIT},
    {"$project" : {
        "F_ID"          : "$f",
        "A_ID"          : "$apps.apId",
        "P_ID"          : "$apps.proc.procID",
        "SRC_ID_SET"    : 
  {"$setUnion" : [ 
 "$apps.proc.s.c.t.sid","$apps.proc.s.d.t.sid","$apps.proc.s.a.t.sid"             
 ]} 
  ,
        "_id"   : 0
    }}
  ])
```

But I feel can be better ...

Comment: `forEach()` would be slow, of course. What do you try to do?

Comment: I need to get certain fields from layer 3 nested array , but the 2x initial $unwind operations take alot of time ...

Comment: Can you share sample data and your approach, perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: added single example document and my attempt to split based on apps.proc.procDate field , but it is still very slow due to the initial double unwind ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully cleat what your final intention is.

```
{"$unwind"  : "$apps"}, 
{"$unwind"  : "$apps.proc"},
{"$match"   : {"apps.proc.procDate" : date}},
{"$limit"   : LIMIT}
```

could be written as

```
{
  $set: {
     apps: {
        $map: {
           input: "$apps",
           as: "app",
           in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                 "$$app",
                 {
                    proc: {
                       $slice: [{
                          $filter: {
                             input: "$$app.proc",
                             cond: { $eq: ["$$this.procDate", date] }
                          }
                       }, LIMIT]
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

For

```
{
  "$project": {
     "F_ID": "$f",
     "A_ID": "$apps.apId",
     "P_ID": "$apps.proc.procID",
     "SRC_ID_SET": { "$setUnion": ["$apps.proc.s.c.t.sid", "$apps.proc.s.d.t.sid", "$apps.proc.s.a.t.sid"] },
     "_id": 0
  }
 }
```

a different approach is

```
{
  $set: {
     apps: {
        $map: {
           input: "$apps",
           as: "app",
           in: {
              A_ID: "$$app.apId",
              P_ID: "$$app.proc.procID",
              SRC_ID_SET: {
                 $setUnion: {
                    $reduce: {
                       input: { $concatArrays: ["$$app.proc.s.c.t.sid", "$$app.proc.s.d.t.sid", "$$app.proc.s.a.t.sid"] },
                       initialValue: [],
                       in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

You still have to run some cosmetics, but I think you got the basic idea of it.